# What happens in an upgrade from 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.2.4?

Tags: upgrade

I want to upgrade Magento **1.9.1.0 to 1.9.2.4** using an app installation program in the cPanel called *Softaculous*.

I wonder what will happen to my Fedex and Paypal settings in the Magento Admin panel? Do the settings remain or do I have to put them back in after the upgrade?

I also have the following:

- an Accessshop theme ( http://accessshopthemes.com/ )
- a calendar from Amasty
- ASCHRODER EXTENSIONS for a 3rd party send mail program - SMTP Pro

Will I have to install everything again after the upgrade or is there a chance it might just work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I have never used Softaculous (or any other auto-installer tool), I would expect an "upgrade" tool to leave your database intact (along with any 3rd party extensions).  Further, I did a quick google search and came across this: https://www.softaculous.com/blog/magento-1-9-2-0-released-with-security-patch-supee-6285/ which says that the upgrade is a "one-click" upgrade and to me implies it will only update core.

However, make sure you have a backup of files and DB prior to running the upgrade script anyway.